# cannot get the currentTime of audio on console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a music player, I want to get the currentTime and duration of the audio. I used ref in the audio tag to select it and use its property. I need the currentTime and duration of the audio, but I'm getting an error. below is the code

```js
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';
import ProgressBar from '../progressBar/progressBar'

class Control extends Component {
   state={
       isPlaying: false,
       songNow: this.props.source,
   }
   player= createRef();  
   
componentWillMount(){
    console.log('WILL UPDATE')
    console.log(this.player)// first log {current: null} then after fraction of second {current:audio} 
}  

componentDidUpdate(){
    
    console.log("COMPONENT DID UPDATE")
    console.log(this.state.isPlaying)
    console.log(this.player.current.duration)// it logs Nan
    setTimeout(()=> console.log(this.player.current.duration), 200)// this shows the duration
   

   if(this.state.isPlaying){
    
        this.player.current.play();
        console.log('if load play')
        console.log(this.props.currentSong.songUrl)
        console.log(this.state.songNow)

       
   }
   else if(!this.state.isPlaying){ 
  
        this.player.current.pause()
       console.log('pause')
   }
}
componentWillReceiveProps=(nextProps)=>{
    console.log("COMPONENT WILL RECEIVE PROPS")
        
    if(this.props.currentSong.songUrl !== nextProps.currentSong.songUrl){
        this.setState({
            songNow: nextProps.currentSong.songUrl,
            isPlaying: true
        })
        this.player.current.pause()
        this.player.current.load()
        this.player.current.play()
        console.log('willrcvprop')
    }
 //some other functions   
      
}
render(){
   
     return ( 
         <div className="controls">
 
                 <p>{this.player.current.currentTime}</p> {/*// Cannot read property 'currentTime' of null*/}
                    <ProgressBar width="200px" player={this.player} />
                <p>{this.player.current.duration}</p> {/*// Cannot read property 'duration' of null*/}

             <audio  ref={this.player} onEnded={()=>this.onNext()}   >
                 <source 
                 src={this.props.currentSong.songUrl}
                 type="audio/mp3"/>
             </audio>
             //some other codes
             )
             }
}
```

this.player.current is showing null

[without removing the 'p'tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU14l.png)

If I comment out both the 'p' tag in return part then on  using console.log in componentWillMount then i get(check the image) [current is null but on opening the 'current' object I get the 'audio'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlbHM.png)

kindly  help to get the 'currentTime' and 'duration' so that i can make my progressbar work
 thanks in advance

Comment: it would seem that 'current' does not exist. Is it created as part of 'player'?

Comment: @Andrew1325 Actually that's attribute of the [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: @Andrew1325 ,hindmost is telling correct you can check the "current" in the image in the console part

Comment: Yeah ok. But current is null so that's why the error. It isn't being initialised.

Comment: when I comment out the <p> tag in the return part I get {current: null} in console from componentWillMount but on clicking{current: null} this i get 'current:audio'. But if I don't comment out the <p>tag  I get {current: null}. I have attached the image of both the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have missed is, on initial render `this.player` might not be fully ready to use and that's why the error. I would suggest to always check if the variable you are using is available or not.

Try this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="controls">
        <p>
          {this.player && this.player.current
            ? this.player.current.currentTime
            : 0}
        </p>
        {/*// Cannot read property 'currentTime' of null*/}
        <ProgressBar width="200px" player={this.player} />
        <p>
          {this.player && this.player.current
            ? this.player.current.duration
            : 0}
        </p>
        {/*// Cannot read property 'duration' of null*/}
        <audio ref={this.player} onEnded={() => this.onNext()}>
          <source src={this.props.currentSong.songUrl} type="audio/mp3" />
        </audio>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Let me know if this works for you.